# Fail to get started with Spring security due to match pattern Exception

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-java-config

I know there are a lost postings with the same upcoming exception. But I tried them all and tried finally 3 different tutorials. And even these example sources are running into the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A universal match pattern ('/**') is defined  before other patterns in the filter chain, causing them to be ignored. Please check the ordering in your <security:http> namespace or FilterChainProxy bean configuration
at org.springframework.security.config.http.DefaultFilterChainValidator.checkPathOrder(DefaultFilterChainValidator.java:49) [spring-security-config-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.config.http.DefaultFilterChainValidator.validate(DefaultFilterChainValidator.java:39) [spring-security-config-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.afterPropertiesSet(FilterChainProxy.java:151) [spring-security-web-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514) [spring-beans-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452) [spring-beans-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
... 21 more
```

Am I doing something crucial wrong? Any advises would be appreciated. As I'd like to secure REST-methods a way with JavaConf would be good or even better as well =)
My web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
version="2.5">

<display-name>Backend</display-name>

<!-- RESTEasy configuration -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap</listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- RESTEasy <-> Spring connector (RESTEasy can access Spring beans) -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.spring.SpringContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<!-- Custom name for main spring configuration -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>


<!-- Spring Security -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

My spring-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.tripple" />
<mvc:annotation-driven />

<!-- Needed for Autowiring -->
<context:annotation-config />

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

<!-- MySQL DataSource -->
<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/tripple" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="" />
</bean>

<!-- Hibernate SessionFactory -->
<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.tripple.entity" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <!-- <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</prop> -->
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>

<security:http create-session="stateless"
    authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
</security:http>

<security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <security:authentication-provider ref="customAuthenticationProvider" />
</security:authentication-manager>
```

And finally my dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd">

<tx:annotation-driven />
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking towords your configuration it seams that your **Spring context loading twice**
go throw following links

[Spring MVC web app: application context starts twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15951257/spring-mvc-web-app-application-context-starts-twice)

[Spring context loading twice with both xml and annotation configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19896421/spring-context-loading-twice-with-both-xml-and-annotation-configuration)

[Application context loading twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12878214/application-context-loading-twice)

another problem might be  a **dependency conflict problem**. 
check for dependency conflicts ,cleaning up dependency conflicts and try to start up the application

hope this will help you !

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried the mentioned links but without success.
There is a dependency conflict problem as I'm using spring 3.1.4 but the direct dependencies itself depend on 3.0.7.
The same issue occured with spring 3.2.5 where they depended on 3.1.4.
Might this really cause the problem?

Comment: are you sure your Spring context not loading twice now

Comment: No, I'm shure that it loading twice. But I have not idea why. It's not an issue like loading the dispatcher-servlet.xml twice as in the first link, the second uses JavaConf and the third has a doubled file in his META-INF folder which is not in my case...

Answer (score 0):

The problem was, that I had a old JavaConf Class in the project as well. Therefore the context was loaded twice. 
Removed the class and everything worked like a charm =)